# SOLR installation and usage help needed

Tags: linux, windows, mysql, database

I have downloaded, and unzipped a SOLR release.

I have run the start.jar in the example directory, and have accessed the admin page in my browser. I am using a virtual server on my computer (wampserver).

What should I do next, and is the adress to the SOLR interface always the same, ie: `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/` ?

How can I POST xml files to the post.jar file as the tutorial says I should do... I have no terminal (i think, because I am using windows)...
I am completely new to SOLR so detailed answer is appreciated.

I have several records in a mysql database now that I want to index with SOLR, how should I do this?

ALSO, in the SOLR tutorial it says SOLR only accepts xml files, then how would I export my records to SOLR from mysql?

Thanks

Comment: this belongs in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already asked most of these questions on stackoverflow:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081669/new-to-solr-some-installation-help-needed
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081990/solr-getting-started-little-help

About Solr accepting XML only: XML is used as an *envelope* for the document. It's used to define what data goes into each field. It does **not** mean that Solr only accepts XML data.